# Django - remove/hide labels for checkboxes

Tags: django, django-forms

I would have thought this would be pretty simple but I have plugged away at this for some time and I can't figure it out.

I have a multiple choice checkbox in a model form which is in a formset. All I want to do is remove the labels from the checkboxes. I can easily remove the label from the field but I can't figure out how to remove the labels from the checkboxes.

I am trying to convert the display of the form to a grid.

From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Here's my form code:

```
    class ResourceEditAddForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.portfolio = kwargs.pop('portfolio')
        super(ResourceEditAddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False 

        self.fields["portfolio"].initial = self.portfolio
        self.fields["portfolio"].required = False
        self.fields["skills"].queryset = self.portfolio.getSkills()

    class Meta:
        model = Resource
        fields = ['portfolio',
                  'name', 
                  'skills', 
                  'pct_availability', 
                  'cost_per_day', 
                  'email',
                  'timezone',
                  'update_request_time',
                  'calendar', 
                  'start_date', 
                  'end_date']
        widgets = {
            'portfolio': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'start_date': DateInput(),
            'end_date': DateInput(),
            'update_request_time': TimeInput(),
            'skills': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        }


ResourceEditAddFormSet = modelformset_factory(
            Resource,
            form=ResourceEditAddForm, 
            extra=0
)
```

I could build a manual form to achieve this but I want to keep using model forms as there's a few fields other than skills which are managed fine by the form.

If anyone can tell me how to hide the labels "animation", "art", etc. next to the checkboxes in forms, css or whatever that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply hide your label from `models.py`. Labels on the form come from `verbose_name` attributes:

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    skills = models...(...,verbose_name="")
```

or

try this under `ResourceEditAddForm`'s `__init__` function:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    self.fields['skills '].label = ''
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Enes. I am probably not explaining this well. 

I can easily remove the label for the field ("Skills"), what I want is to remove the labels for the checkbox options ("Animation", "Art", etc.). These are provided by Django in the model form from the many-to-many relationship  Resource <-> Skill. I could achieve this in a manual form, but I am wanting to stick with a model form.

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have resolved this by slightly customising the widget:

```
    skills_widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
    skills_widget.option_template_name = "django/forms/widgets/input.html"
    model = Resource
    fields = ['portfolio',
              'name', 
              'skills', 
              'end_date']
    widgets = {
        'portfolio': forms.HiddenInput(),
        'skills': skills_widget
    },
```

So this replaces the full template for the checkbox (which wraps the input in a label) with just the input part.